# Clean Architecture: Should the domain layer control whether add to database or not after specific action?

Tags: android, clean-architecture

If I have a use case **doPayment** and after success, I need to add this payment to a database.

My question is, Shall I create an interface for this action e.g, **PaymentAPI** and another interface **PaymentRespository** to store this payment?

The same for the login/register use cases.

I'm asking because all tutorials and examples explain the simple and straightforward scenarios where all use cases are just getting or putting data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Clean Architecture you would use repository pattern for this. You define the repository interface in the use case layer and the implementation in the gateway/framework layer.

By that the use case layer decides about what needs to be made persistent and when but does not depend on the concrete data store.

Comment: Sure, the domain depends on abstractions only. My question is should I create two interfaces one for the paymentAPI and the other for the repository?

Comment: Assuming that with PaymentAPI u mean "access to an external service doing the payment operation" then following "Single Responsibility Principle" and "Interface segregation" u should define two independent interfaces.

Comment: So, the domain layer here will control whether to call save the result from the API to the repository? Isn't that?

Comment: Yes. The domain layer makes the decision while the implementation details are outside of this layer